# string or binary data would be truncated in select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is my query after execution it is throwing error **string or binary data would be truncated.**

```
Declare @mString Varchar(max)
Set @mString='Select ''Some text....'''-- (string length is greater than 42000)
exec(@mString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works?

Declare @mString NVarchar(max)
Set @mString=N'Select ''Some text....'''-- (string length is greater than 42000)

exec(@mString)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is problem in limit of expression in `SET` statement. So you need to split your expression on portions by 4000 chars i.e. if you have expression with length 4001 char you should:

```
declare @string nvarchar(max)

set @string = 'some text with 4000 chars length'
set @string = @string + 'text with 1 char length'

exec(@string)
```